# Mercurial does not startup upon system launch [FreeBSD 9.0 Apache22]

Tags: apache, mercurial, apache2, freebsd

Struggling to find a root of issue with Apache22 and mercurial. Everything seems to work right — made repository, folder with properly configured hgweb.cgi, set permissions etc.

Here comes the main problem. Everything works *only* if I (re)start Apache manually, using `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache22 restart` otherwise, using `service apache22 restart` or while whole system is booting, I'm getting up and running Apache with website accessible. But once trying to access web interface it gives me "Internal Server Error" in browser and next messages in `http-error.log`

```
[Fri Apr 20 17:49:40 2012] [error] [client 10.20.30.34] env: 
[Fri Apr 20 17:49:40 2012] [error] [client 10.20.30.34] python
[Fri Apr 20 17:49:40 2012] [error] [client 10.20.30.34] : 
[Fri Apr 20 17:49:40 2012] [error] [client 10.20.30.34] No such file or directory
[Fri Apr 20 17:49:40 2012] [error] [client 10.20.30.34] Premature end of script headers: hgweb.cgi
```

My guess is that it could be an issue with environment variables but what a heck is a difference between `service` run and direct call of script from `/usr/local/rc.d/` ? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check PATH, it look likes python is not in your path. Maybe add /usr/local/bin to the path of the www user

Answer (score 0):

Solution is really about making user running httpd (**www** in my case) to have *$PATH* adjusted. But it might not be obvious for everyone so here is what I did:

created */usr/local/etc/apache22/envvars.d/path.env* with content

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

This require Apache to have *env_module* loaded but this looks like a standard module to be loaded in default configuration.